# Upload imagem + parametros HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, post, file-upload, jersey

Tenho um servidor Rest e preciso fazer upload de imagens e também enviar parametros.
Já fiz várias pesquisas mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar o client.
Pelo navegador funciona certo, via código eu consigo enviar a imagem mas o parametro não. 
Segue o código do servidor - Jersey 1.17.

```
@POST
@Path("/query")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream, 
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentHeader, 
                        @FormDataParam("codvendedor") String codVendedor)
{
    System.out.println("Rep"+codVendedor);
    String path = "C:\\arquivosXML\\"+contentHeader.getFileName();

    System.out.println("path "+path);

    saveFile(fileInputStream, path);

    String output = "File saved";
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(output).build();
}
```

Segue o cliente

```
public void post2() throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    String paramToSend = "4";
    File fileToUpload = new File("C:\\doc\\fachada2.png");
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    String userCredentials = "rep4:44";

    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));

    HttpURLConnection  connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URL_UPLOAD  ).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // This sets request method to POST.

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    connection.setRequestProperty ("Connection", "keep-alive");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


    DataOutputStream  output = null;
    try
    {
        output = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes("--" + boundary+"\r\n");
        output.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"fachada2.png\""+"\r\n");
        output.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png;"+"\r\n");
        output.writeBytes("\r\n");

        byte[] anexo = convertInputstreamToBytes(fileToUpload);
        output.write(anexo);

        output.writeBytes("--" + boundary+"\r\n");
        output.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"codvendedor\""+"\r\n");
        output.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"+"\r\n");
        output.writeBytes(paramToSend+"\r\n");

        output.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--" + "\r\n");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }
    }


    int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode); 
}
```

Comment: Olhando sua requisição, acho que faltou informar o campo `Content-Length`, segundo o RFC, ele não é obrigatório, mas é um padrão adotado por alguns servidores. Poderia também comparar a sua requisição com a requisição do Browser (usando o Developer Tools), só como verificação. Acho que essa resposta pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12119430/3404639.

Comment: Com ou sem o content-length o resultado é o mesmo, o arquivo vai, mas o parametro sempre é null.